# Visual Studio showing wrong documentation for .NET

Tags: visual-studio-2019

This is what VS is showing me for some classes:
[image: VS Intellisense showing wrong tooltip]

I checked the XML file containing the documentation:
[image: Tuple class]

As this references the 4.x doc file, I checked this file:
[image: 4.x xml doc]

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?
I tried to repair VS and reinstalled the .NET SDK but this didn't fixed the problem. I suspect VS has some sort of cache for the XML doc, but my search didn't return anything helpful.
I'm on the latest version of VS 2019 16.7.2. This problem is present for quite some updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by first completely uninstalling all .NET SDK and then reinstalling. Funny thing was, that after a simple new installation all assemblies were missing in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2
```

I then ran a repair on the new installation and this fixed the issue.
Antoher thing that is now different is, that the 4.x folder is missing. However, it's working now.